# Which Regression methods are suitable for binary valued features and continuous output?

Tags: machine-learning, static-analysis, regression, svm, random-forest

I want to build a machine learning model to regression on continuous output given binary valued features(0,1). the dimension of my problem is around 200. 
which of the flowing methods seems suitable  for this kind of problem ?

- SVR with different Kernels
- Regression random forest
- MARS
- Gradient boosting with regression tree
- Kernel regression (Nadya-Watson Kernel regression)
- LSR and LARS
- Stochastic gradient boosting

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively speaking, anything requiring the calculation of a gradient is going to struggle on binary values. From your list, SVR and Forests would be the first place I'd look for a benchmark solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at expectation maximization for Bernoully mixture models.
It deals with binary input sets. You can find theory in book:
Christopher M. Bishop. "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning".